# iMacro, how to set variables from selected text?

Tags: imacros

It's a framed site, and the `TAG` command created when I highlight the text is:

```
FRAME F=0
TAG POS=1 TYPE=A ATTR=TXT:TEST<SP>TEST
```

I'm trying to figure out how to extract the `TEST<SP>TEST` part and set it to a variable, so I can put it in a form on another tab.

Answer (score 2):

try this:

```
FRAME F=0
TAG POS=1 TYPE=A ATTR=TXT:TESTTEST extract=txt
```